# How do I damage Thunderblight Ganon?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I tried the boss fight against Thunderblight Ganon, and was very shocked, even after watching video and guides, at how fast he is. I knew he came in to attack fast, but he dashes away before I can damage him.

I tried a perfect parry, but the electricity makes me drop my shield. I also tried a perfect dodge to flurry rush, but he is just too fast. The only way I could get through is when he activates Daruk's Protection, but that goes away after three uses.

How do I get past his speedy attack, retreat, and shield to damage him consistently? (If it helps the answer, I beat the other three Divine Beasts, so I have those weapons and powers, but I don't have the Master Sword yet.)

Comment: Think about the trouble kleric had with this one: He defeated it with tree branches!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Zelda Wiki entry on [Thunderblight Ganon](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Thunderblight_Ganon), as well as my own experience fighting him:

Phase 1: The strategy here is straightforward, though it may take some practice: block his attacks, and after blocking his attacks, you should have time to attack once or twice. I used a spear because of the reach (I found it helped land an extra hit), though I am sure many other weapons (eg Master Sword) could be used as well. However I would recommend staying away from 2-handed weapons, as they lack the speed to land the necessary hits.

Phase 2: I found this phase the easiest. After getting his health down to 1/2, Thunderblight Ganon will begin levitating out of reach, dropping pillars around the room which he strikes with electricity. Use [Magnesis](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Magnesis) to pick up a pillar and shock Thunderblight Ganon with a pillar he has charged with electricity.

Phase 3: Now Thunderblight Ganon will repeat his method of attack in the first phase, but much faster and more aggressively. This is the phase I always had problems with, but the strategy remains the same: block when he attacks, and make good use of the limited time after the block to land a hit or two.

If you're still having trouble, you can also use some food or elixirs that give you high electricity resistance to minimize damage during the fight (eg [Electro Meat Skewers](https://rankedboost.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild/food-cooking-recipes/#electro) or [Electro Elixir](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Food#Electro_Elixir)). A good list can be found [here](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Food), just search for "Electro".

Comment: A few notes: In phase 1 you can use perfect parries when Gannon charges. It takes a bit of practice to get the timing right but it stuns him for long enough to land several hits. You can skip phase 3 entirely by arranging to be right beneath him when you shock him - he falls to the ground stunned for long enough that you can just kill him while he lays at your feet. And if you don't, you can just block all of his phase 3 sword attacks with your shield and attack him while he's charging up his laser attack.

Answer (score 2):

As per Jeff's comment I believe I just regular dodged and hammered attack when he comes in to hit you, I had the Master Sword but any sword or spear (for their quick attack compared to two handed weapons) should do I would say. If I remember rightly he is fast but if you can dodge his attack he should stand still long enough to be hit a few times, and I believe if you attack his shield it gets damaged and destroyed so he can't block.

Later on (after half health) is when he gets really tricky... But I won't spoil that for you if you haven't reached that part yet (unless you want tips for that part of the battle too) and I can't see how to do spoiler tags from my phone.